# Is it possible to a variable/class be accessible to only other specific class?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have a class that is available just to other specific class, and inaccessible to the "rest" of the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a private nested class within the class that requires access.

Answer (score 0):

For **one** class, you make nest one class inside another. If you need to later expand this, you can do it by breaking the Solution up among different Projects (dlls), marking a class `internal`, and using the [`[InternalVisibleTo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute.